# FFMPEG Watermark multiple lines only first vible

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I am adding 2 lines of watermarks but only first is visible

```js
ffmpeg()
  .input(tempLocalPath)
  .complexFilter([
    `[0:v]drawtext=text='${watermarkTextLine1}':x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h-460):fontsize=24:fontcolor=white@0.5:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf`,
    `[0:v]drawtext=text='${watermarkTextLine2}':x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h-200):fontsize=32:fontcolor=red:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf`,
  ])
  .output(
    path.join(tempLocalDir, video_cid.replace(".mp4", "-") + "watermarked.mp4"),
  )
  .on("end", function () {
    // Send the watermarked video as a response
    res.download(
      path.join(
        tempLocalDir,
        video_cid.replace(".mp4", "-") + "watermarked.mp4",
      ),
      "video.mp4",
      function (downloadError) {
        if (downloadError) {
          console.error("Error during download:", downloadError);
        }

        // Clean up: Delete the temporary local file
        fs.unlink(tempLocalPath, (unlinkError) => {
          if (unlinkError) {
            console.error(
              "Error deleting the temporary video file:",
              unlinkError,
            );
          }
        });
      },
    );
  })
  .inputFormat("mp4")
  .run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.complexFilter([
    `[0:v]drawtext=text='${watermarkTextLine1}':x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h-460):fontsize=24:fontcolor=white@0.5:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf[filter_1]`,
    `[filter_1]drawtext=text='${watermarkTextLine2}':x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h-200):fontsize=32:fontcolor=red:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf`,
  ])
```

Because two filters had same input `[0:v]`, and same output (but ffmpeg select one).
We need to use the output of the first filter for the input of the next filter.